# org.neo4j.driver.exceptions.ClientException Unknown function 'ID'

Tags: java, spring-boot, neo4j, cypher

I cloned the belowing example code.
https://github.com/neo4j-examples/movies-java-spring-data-neo4j

I started same application in my computer then it throwed an exception.

org.neo4j.driver.exceptions.ClientException Unknown function 'ID'

-Neo4j version : 3.5.16 community

-Spring boot example code and pom.xml dependency are same in GitHub link

-Computer language is Turkish and Windows 10

Stacktrace is this

```
2020-04-08 00:06:35.871  INFO 24904 --- [nio-8096-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-04-08 00:06:35.872  INFO 24904 --- [nio-8096-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-04-08 00:06:35.894  INFO 24904 --- [nio-8096-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 22 ms
2020-04-08 00:06:36.219  INFO 24904 --- [nio-8096-exec-3] Driver                                   : Direct driver instance 334920911 created for server address localhost:7687
2020-04-08 00:06:36.809  WARN 24904 --- [nio-8096-exec-4] org.neo4j.ogm.session.Neo4jSession       : Error executing query : Unknown function 'ID' (line 1, column 126 (offset: 125))
"MATCH (n:`Movie`) WHERE n.`title` =~ $`title_0` WITH n RETURN n,[ [ (n)<-[r_a1:`ACTED_IN`]-(p1:`Person`) | [ r_a1, p1 ] ] ], ID(n)"
                                                                                                                              ^. Rolling back transaction.
2020-04-08 00:06:36.841 ERROR 24904 --- [nio-8096-exec-4] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.neo4j.driver.exceptions.ClientException: Unknown function 'ID' (line 1, column 126 (offset: 125))
"MATCH (n:`Movie`) WHERE n.`title` =~ $`title_0` WITH n RETURN n,[ [ (n)<-[r_a1:`ACTED_IN`]-(p1:`Person`) | [ r_a1, p1 ] ] ], ID(n)"
                                                                                                                              ^] with root cause

org.neo4j.driver.exceptions.ClientException: Unknown function 'ID' (line 1, column 126 (offset: 125))
"MATCH (n:`Movie`) WHERE n.`title` =~ $`title_0` WITH n RETURN n,[ [ (n)<-[r_a1:`ACTED_IN`]-(p1:`Person`) | [ r_a1, p1 ] ] ], ID(n)"
                                                                                                                              ^
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.util.Futures.blockingGet(Futures.java:143) ~[neo4j-java-driver-4.0.0.jar:4.0.0-d03d93ede8ad65657eeb90ed890757203ecfaa7a]
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.InternalResult.blockingGet(InternalResult.java:128) ~[neo4j-java-driver-4.0.0.jar:4.0.0-d03d93ede8ad65657eeb90ed890757203ecfaa7a]
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.InternalResult.hasNext(InternalResult.java:64) ~[neo4j-java-driver-4.0.0.jar:4.0.0-d03d93ede8ad65657eeb90ed890757203ecfaa7a]
    at org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.bolt.response.BoltResponse.columns(BoltResponse.java:65) ~[neo4j-ogm-bolt-driver-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
    at org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.bolt.response.GraphRowModelResponse.<init>(GraphRowModelResponse.java:42) ~[neo4j-ogm-bolt-driver-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
    at org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.bolt.request.BoltRequest.execute(BoltRequest.java:162) ~[neo4j-ogm-bolt-driver-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
    at org.neo4j.ogm.session.delegates.LoadByTypeDelegate.lambda$loadAll$0(LoadByTypeDelegate.java:99) ~[neo4j-ogm-core-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
    at org.neo4j.ogm.session.Neo4jSession.doInTransaction(Neo4jSession.java:590) ~[neo4j-ogm-core-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
    at org.neo4j.ogm.session.Neo4jSession.doInTransaction(Neo4jSession.java:564) ~[neo4j-ogm-core-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
    at org.neo4j.ogm.session.delegates.LoadByTypeDelegate.loadAll(LoadByTypeDelegate.java:95) ~[neo4j-ogm-core-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
    at org.neo4j.ogm.session.delegates.LoadByTypeDelegate.loadAll(LoadByTypeDelegate.java:168) ~[neo4j-ogm-core-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
    at org.neo4j.ogm.session.Neo4jSession.loadAll(Neo4jSession.java:295) ~[neo4j-ogm-core-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:282) ~[spring-core-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.transaction.SharedSessionCreator$SharedSessionInvocationHandler.lambda$invoke$1(SharedSessionCreator.java:121) ~[spring-data-neo4j-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.transaction.SharedSessionCreator$SharedSessionInvocationHandler.invokeInTransaction(SharedSessionCreator.java:159) ~[spring-data-neo4j-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.transaction.SharedSessionCreator$SharedSessionInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedSessionCreator.java:123) ~[spring-data-neo4j-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy93.loadAll(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.query.GraphQueryExecution$CollectionExecution.execute(GraphQueryExecution.java:92) ~[spring-data-neo4j-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.query.PartTreeNeo4jQuery.doExecute(PartTreeNeo4jQuery.java:74) ~[spring-data-neo4j-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.query.AbstractGraphRepositoryQuery.execute(AbstractGraphRepositoryQuery.java:57) ~[spring-data-neo4j-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:618) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:605) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:366) ~[spring-tx-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:95) ~[spring-aop-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy104.findByTitleLike(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:282) ~[spring-core-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.support.ReflectionRepositoryInvoker.invoke(ReflectionRepositoryInvoker.java:256) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.support.ReflectionRepositoryInvoker.invokeQueryMethod(ReflectionRepositoryInvoker.java:191) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.core.support.UnwrappingRepositoryInvokerFactory$UnwrappingRepositoryInvoker.invokeQueryMethod(UnwrappingRepositoryInvokerFactory.java:104) ~[spring-data-rest-core-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySearchController.executeQueryMethod(RepositorySearchController.java:358) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySearchController.executeSearch(RepositorySearchController.java:180) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:888) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:367) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:860) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1598) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
    Suppressed: org.neo4j.driver.internal.util.ErrorUtil$InternalExceptionCause: null
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.util.ErrorUtil.newNeo4jError(ErrorUtil.java:79) ~[neo4j-java-driver-4.0.0.jar:4.0.0-d03d93ede8ad65657eeb90ed890757203ecfaa7a]
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.async.inbound.InboundMessageDispatcher.handleFailureMessage(InboundMessageDispatcher.java:105) ~[neo4j-java-driver-4.0.0.jar:4.0.0-d03d93ede8ad65657eeb90ed890757203ecfaa7a]
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.messaging.v1.MessageReaderV1.unpackFailureMessage(MessageReaderV1.java:83) ~[neo4j-java-driver-4.0.0.jar:4.0.0-d03d93ede8ad65657eeb90ed890757203ecfaa7a]
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.messaging.v1.MessageReaderV1.read(MessageReaderV1.java:59) ~[neo4j-java-driver-4.0.0.jar:4.0.0-d03d93ede8ad65657eeb90ed890757203ecfaa7a]
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.async.inbound.InboundMessageHandler.channelRead0(InboundMessageHandler.java:83) ~[neo4j-java-driver-4.0.0.jar:4.0.0-d03d93ede8ad65657eeb90ed890757203ecfaa7a]
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.async.inbound.InboundMessageHandler.channelRead0(InboundMessageHandler.java:35) ~[neo4j-java-driver-4.0.0.jar:4.0.0-d03d93ede8ad65657eeb90ed890757203ecfaa7a]
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105) ~[neo4j-java-driver-4.0.0.jar:4.0.0-d03d93ede8ad65657eeb90ed890757203ecfaa7a]
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374) ~[neo4j-java-driver-4.0.0.jar:4.0.0-d03d93ede8ad65657eeb90ed890757203ecfaa7a]
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360) ~[neo4j-java-driver-4.0.0.jar:4.0.0-d03d93ede8ad65657eeb90ed890757203ecfaa7a]
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352) ~[neo4j-java-driver-4.0.0.jar:4.0.0-d03d93ede8ad65657eeb90ed890757203ecfaa7a]
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:328) ~[neo4j-java-driver-4.0.0.jar:4.0.0-d03d93ede8ad65657eeb90ed890757203ecfaa7a]
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:302) ~[neo4j-java-driver-4.0.0.jar:4.0.0-d03d93ede8ad65657eeb90ed890757203ecfaa7a]
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.async.inbound.MessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageDecoder.java:47) ~[neo4j-java-driver-4.0.0.jar:4.0.0-d03d93ede8ad65657eeb90ed890757203ecfaa7a]
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374) ~[neo4j-java-driver-4.0.0.jar:4.0.0-d03d93ede8ad65657eeb90ed890757203ecfaa7a]
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360) ~[neo4j-java-driver-4.0.0.jar:4.0.0-d03d93ede8ad65657eeb90ed890757203ecfaa7a]
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352) ~[neo4j-java-driver-4.0.0.jar:4.0.0-d03d93ede8ad65657eeb90ed890757203ecfaa7a]
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:328) ~[neo4j-java-driver-4.0.0.jar:4.0.0-d03d93ede8ad65657eeb90ed890757203ecfaa7a]
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:315) ~[neo4j-java-driver-4.0.0.jar:4.0.0-d03d93ede8ad65657eeb90ed890757203ecfaa7a]
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:429) ~[neo4j-java-driver-4.0.0.jar:4.0.0-d03d93ede8ad65657eeb90ed890757203ecfaa7a]
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:283) ~[neo4j-java-driver-4.0.0.jar:4.0.0-d03d93ede8ad65657eeb90ed890757203ecfaa7a]
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374) ~[neo4j-java-driver-4.0.0.jar:4.0.0-d03d93ede8ad65657eeb90ed890757203ecfaa7a]
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360) ~[neo4j-java-driver-4.0.0.jar:4.0.0-d03d93ede8ad65657eeb90ed890757203ecfaa7a]
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352) ~[neo4j-java-driver-4.0.0.jar:4.0.0-d03d93ede8ad65657eeb90ed890757203ecfaa7a]
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1422) ~[neo4j-java-driver-4.0.0.jar:4.0.0-d03d93ede8ad65657eeb90ed890757203ecfaa7a]
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374) ~[neo4j-java-driver-4.0.0.jar:4.0.0-d03d93ede8ad65657eeb90ed890757203ecfaa7a]
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360) ~[neo4j-java-driver-4.0.0.jar:4.0.0-d03d93ede8ad65657eeb90ed890757203ecfaa7a]
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:931) ~[neo4j-java-driver-4.0.0.jar:4.0.0-d03d93ede8ad65657eeb90ed890757203ecfaa7a]
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:163) ~[neo4j-java-driver-4.0.0.jar:4.0.0-d03d93ede8ad65657eeb90ed890757203ecfaa7a]
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:700) ~[neo4j-java-driver-4.0.0.jar:4.0.0-d03d93ede8ad65657eeb90ed890757203ecfaa7a]
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:635) ~[neo4j-java-driver-4.0.0.jar:4.0.0-d03d93ede8ad65657eeb90ed890757203ecfaa7a]
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:552) ~[neo4j-java-driver-4.0.0.jar:4.0.0-d03d93ede8ad65657eeb90ed890757203ecfaa7a]
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:514) ~[neo4j-java-driver-4.0.0.jar:4.0.0-d03d93ede8ad65657eeb90ed890757203ecfaa7a]
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$6.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:1044) ~[neo4j-java-driver-4.0.0.jar:4.0.0-d03d93ede8ad65657eeb90ed890757203ecfaa7a]
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[neo4j-java-driver-4.0.0.jar:4.0.0-d03d93ede8ad65657eeb90ed890757203ecfaa7a]
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[neo4j-java-driver-4.0.0.jar:4.0.0-d03d93ede8ad65657eeb90ed890757203ecfaa7a]
        ... 1 common frames omitted
```

Please help me.

Comment: I hope you have already opened a Bug for this issue https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/12454

Comment: Yes I have already opened a bug but may be someone had solved this problem before.

Comment: Can you add the complete stack trace to your question?

Comment: I added the stack trace.